# Missing argument 1 for MagazineController@edit()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

**Laravel 4.2 Project**

I have set up an edit function in MagazineController that takes an $id. That method can be seen below:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $magazine = Magazine::findOrFail($id);

    dd($magazine);
}
```

I have also set up the routes for this view which can be seen when I run *php artisan routes*.

The route prints out as: *magazine/{magazine}/edit*

When I hit the above URL though it tells me that the first parameter is missing. For some reason the wildcard is not automatically being passed through. The route is set up using a route resource.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin The edit route is as follows: GET|HEAD /magazine/{magazine}/edit

Comment: When you say 'the wildcard is not automatically being passed through' do you mean that the value of $id is not getting passed to the function?

Answer (score 0):

the value passed inside {} braces should be same as the parameter passed into the edit function of controller method. In your case {magazine} -> $magazine And One more thing you need check that if other routes are being defined that have same pattern as of edit.

To debug :: just use separate route and test the code.

!!Happy Coding

Comment: Hi, I already tried setting them both to $magazine and it didn't work either.

Comment: Did u try setting up a separate route on top of routes file.. sometimes the routes get overridden.. put the route as  - Route::put('magazine/{magazine}/edit'); - on the very beginning of routes file.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to get this working by manually adding the *Route::get()* to the **Routes.php** file. For some reason it wasn't working inside the *Route::resource()* but it works outside of it.

Thank you to everyone who helped me out!

Comment: It will work... show me the way you had defined the Route::resource().